# Create an Excel Macro to filter sheets with a certain title to a new workbook

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an Excel Workbook containing ~50 different sheets. These sheets are organized into raw data and organized data summaries.

The data summaries are sheets that I'm trying to upload to an Access database, and these sheets all include the string "Summary" or "Sum" as part of their name. I'm new to VBA and I'm wondering if there is a way I can set up a script to filter out the sheets so that I am left with just the summary sheets and not the raw data sheets as part of my workbook.

Ideally I would copy the summary sheets over to a new Excel workbook since I don't want to lose my raw data. Any help? Or is this not even possible?

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro yet? That would be a good place to start to get some code.

Comment: I agree this is a good place to start and it has been helpful, the place I get stuck is trying to identify only the sheets that have the string "sum" or "summary" as part of their name

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`InStr()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function) function works great for this! Bonus here is the sheets will be hidden and **not** deleted.

Since "Summary" contains the string "Sum" already, I didn't bother putting the logic in for that.

**Macro to Hide Sheets containing "Sum"**

```
Sub HideSheets()

   Dim sht As Worksheet

   For Each sht In Worksheets
      If (InStr(sht.Name, "Sum")) Then
         sht.Visible = xlSheetHidden
      End If
   Next

End Sub
```

**Macro to Show ALL Sheets**

```
Sub ShowSheets()

   Dim sht As Worksheet

   For Each sht In Worksheets
      sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
   Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option explicit

Sub CopySumSheetsOver()

Const SUBSTRING as string = "Sum" 'Change this to whatever string you want to search for.'

With thisworkbook

Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim SheetNames() as string
Redim SheetNames(1 to .worksheets.count)

Dim SheetIndex as long

For each ws in .worksheets
SheetIndex = SheetIndex + 1
SheetNames(SheetIndex) = ws.name
Next ws

Redim preserve sheetnames(1 to sheetindex)

SheetNames = filter(sheetnames,SUBSTRING,True,vbTextCompare) 'vbBinaryCompare is faster, but case-sensitive, use whichever one you need.'

Dim DestinationWorkbook as workbook
Set DestinationWorkbook = application.workbooks.add

.worksheets(SheetNames).copy destinationworkbook.worksheets(destinationworkbook.worksheets.count)

End with

End sub
```

Untested, written on mobile. Sorry for bad formatting.